# Advice on optimizing this C program?

Tags: c, arrays, optimization, nested-loops

wondering if there is a way I can shrink this program. I don't like the look of the 5 printf/scanf pairs, but I can't think of a way to use a for loop to shrink it. I have trouble with matching the scanf calls to the printf calls.

```
for(i = 1; i < 6; i++)
    printf("Enter row %d", i);
```

this part is easy, however, the scanf calls and assignments into the array are baffling me.

```
//Sums row and column
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int a[5][5];
    int row[5] = {0}, col[5] = {0};
    int i, j;

    printf("\t--Enter a 5x5 chart--\n");
    printf("\tEnter row #1: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &a[0][0], &a[0][1], &a[0][2], &a[0][3], &a[0][4]);

    printf("\tEnter row #2: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &a[1][0], &a[1][1], &a[1][2], &a[1][3], &a[1][4]);

    printf("\tEnter row #3: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &a[2][0], &a[2][1], &a[2][2], &a[2][3], &a[2][4]);

    printf("\tEnter row #4: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &a[3][0], &a[3][1], &a[3][2], &a[3][3], &a[3][4]);

    printf("\tEnter row #5: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &a[4][0], &a[4][1], &a[4][2], &a[4][3], &a[4][4]);

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                    row[j] += a[j][i];
                    col[j] += a[i][j];
            }
    }

    printf("\tRow sums: %d %d %d %d %d\n", row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]);
    printf("\tColumn sums: %d %d %d %d %d\n", col[0], col[1], col[2], col[3], col[4]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem to have `input_row` function (with or without a for loop to scanf cells) and to call it N times?

Comment: User input is extraordinarily difficult to predict. You might want to make sure you got what you expected: `if (scanf(...) != 5) /* user is being creative */;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace:

```
printf("\tEnter row #1: ");
scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &a[0][0], &a[0][1], &a[0][2], &a[0][3], &a[0][4]);         
...
printf("\tEnter row #5: ");
scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &a[4][0], &a[4][1], &a[4][2], &a[4][3], &a[4][4]);
```

with:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("\tEnter row #%d: ", i+1);
    scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &a[i][0], &a[i][1], &a[i][2], &a[i][3], &a[i][4]);
}
```

Comment: ... and rename the variables `i` and `j` to `j` and `k`, respectively. +1.

Comment: After I hit post, I saw the declaration for i in the original code and edited my answert to remove the declaration of i in my new code.

Comment: Thank you. In retrospect, this seems obvious, and I feel a little foolish for not seeing it myself earlier.

Comment: @Bowlslaw It's a bit difficult to comprehend how anyone "can't think of a way" when the printf statements are so simply related to the scanf statements. Perhaps you can say something about your thought process and what you were missing or what got in the way. BTW, the scanf should also be expressed as a loop: `for(j = 0; j < COLS; ++j) scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);` ... and all those '5's should be replaced by manifest constants such as ROWS and COLS. Also, consider using r and c or row and col instead of i and j, for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

What about the following to read the input:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
   printf("\tEnter row #%i: ", i+1);
   scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &a[i][0], &a[i][1], &a[i][2], &a[i][3], &a[i][4]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    printf ("\tEnter row #%d: ", (i+1));
    scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &a[i][0], &a[i][1], &a[i][2], &a[i][3], &a[i][4]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
int rowIndex;

... 

for(rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 5; rowIndex++)
{
   printf("\tEnter row #%d: ", rowIndex+1);
    scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &a[rowIndex][0], &a[rowIndex][1], &a[rowIndex][2], &a[rowIndex][3], &a[rowIndex][4]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jim Balter already mentioned this in his comment to the currently accepted answer, but it deserves being posted as an answer since it is a better and more maintanable solution.

```
for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) 
{
    printf("\tEnter row #%d: ", i+1);

    for( j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++ )
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i][j] ) ;
    }
}
```

Note that scanf() uses any whitespace as a delimiter so, the 'row' need not be entered in a single scanf() call.